# TSQL Statement IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a small problem with the IN SQL statement. I was just wondering if anyone could help me?

```
@Ids = "1,2,3,4,5"

SELECT * FROM Nav WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR,NavigationID) IN (CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Ids))
```

This is coming back with the error below, I am sure this is pretty simple!

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,' to data type int.
```

Answer (score 4):

The SQL IN clause does not accept a single variable to represent a list of values -- no database does, without using dynamic SQL.  Otherwise, you could [use a Table Valued Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx) (SQL Server 2000+) to pull the values out of the list & return them as a table that you can join against.

Dynamic SQL example:

```
EXEC('SELECT * 
        FROM Nav 
       WHERE NavigationID IN ('+ @Ids +')')
```

I recommend reading [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) before using dynamic SQL on SQL Server.

Comment: As a side note, dynamic queries are not well handled by the queries optimizer, but that was not the question.

Comment: @PulsarBlow: "well handled" is vague, and incorrect - there's no difference between a dynamic and a non-dynamic query to the optimizer.  `EXEC` however has been known to not cache query plans, while `sp_executesql` does.  I recommend you read the link about the curse & blessings of dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1):

Jason:

First create a function like this

```
Create     FUNCTION [dbo].[ftDelimitedAsTable](@dlm char, @string varchar(8000))
RETURNS 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------
declare @dlm  char, @string varchar(1000)
set @dlm=','; set @string='t1,t2,t3';
-- tHIS FUNCION RETUNRS IN THE ASCENDING ORDER
-- 19TH Apr 06
------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
--declare
    @table_var TABLE 
    (id int identity(1,1),
        r varchar(1000) 
     )
AS
BEGIN
    declare @n int,@i int
    set @n=dbo.fnCountChars(@dlm,@string)+1
    SET @I =1
    while @I <= @N
        begin
            insert @table_var
                select dbo.fsDelimitedString(@dlm,@string,@i)
            set @I= @I+1

        end
    if @n =1 insert @TABLE_VAR VALUES(@STRING)
    delete  from @table_var where r=''
    return
END
```

And then

```
set quoted_identifier off
declare @ids varchar(max)
select @Ids = "1,2,3,4,5"
declare @nav table ( navigationid int identity(1,1),theother bigint)
insert @nav(theother) select 10 union select 11 union select 15
SELECT * FROM @Nav WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR,NavigationID) IN (select id from dbo.ftDelimitedAsTable(',',@Ids))

select * from dbo.ftDelimitedAsTable(',',@Ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is not possible with the SQL `IN` statement.  You cannot pass a string to it and expect that string to be parsed.  IN is for specific, hard-coded values.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do what you want to do here.
One is to create a 'dynamic sql' query and execute it, after substituting in your IN list.

```
DECLARE @query varchar(max);
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM Nav WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR,NavigationID) IN (' + @Ids + ')'
exec (@query)
```

This can have performance impacts and other complications. Generally I'd try to avoid it.

The other method is to use a User Defined Function (UDF) to split the string into its component parts and then query against that.
There's a post detailing how to create that function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-recor)

Once the function exists, it's trivial to join onto it

```
SELECT * FROM Nav
CROSS APPLY dbo.StringSplit(@Ids) a
WHERE a.s = CONVERT(varchar, Nav.NavigationId)
```

NB- the 'a.s' field reference is based on the linked function, which stores the split value in a column named 's'. This may differ based on the implementation of your string split function

This is nice because it uses a set based approach to the query rather than an IN subquery, but a CROSS JOIN may be a little complex for the moment, so if you want to maintain the IN syntax then the following should work:

```
SELECT * FROM Nav
WHERE Nav.NavigationId IN
    (SELECT CONVERT(int, a.s) AS Value
    FROM dbo.StringSplit(@Ids) a
```